# UIButton textColor for UIControlStateHighlighted in iOS8 issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, ios8, uicontrolstate

I always set the `UIColor` of highlighted `UIButton` with:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

But in `iOS8` it doesn't work for me (and setting the `UIColor` in storyboard doesn't work too).

But this code works fine for `iOS7`.

Comment: how was your button created?

Comment: in storyboard with type custom and without any images

Comment: is there an IBOutlet created and property synthesize?

Comment: By the way. That works for me and it's not deprecated for iOS 8 so you may have some issues in storyboard somewhere. I would just suggest creating the button progrnatically in viewDidLoad and you'll be fine using the same code you've always used

Comment: I tried to create the button in code, it works. But I don't need to create it in code, I like to use storyboard, and it's not good to change all the buttons in the application in code. So the problem is in Storyboard

Comment: so are you setting the text color or the tint color in storyboard for event changes?

Comment: text color for the UIButton normal state I set in Storyboard. The text color for Highlighted state I tried to set in Storyboard , that didn't help. Then I tried to set in Code, and that didn't help too

Comment: Well the code is easy:
-(void)viewDidLoad{
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    [button setTitle:@"Hey" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
I can't help you with the storyboard without being there to see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66206/discussion-between-soulshined-and-paul-galavic).

Comment: I have same issue, the button text color is always white... could you fixed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have the button on system style? Try change the button type to custom in Identity Inspector.